# Are Grey Wardens from "Dragon Age" inspired by Night's Watch from "A Song of Ice and Fire"?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, inspiration, dragon-age

Does anyone know if BioWare used the Night's Watch as an inspiration for their Grey Wardens?

Duncan could be Benjen Stark and the Human story could be right out of *A Song of Ice and Fire*.

In addition, the oaths the Grey Wardens take and the training they go through are very similar.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [David Gaider's tweet](https://twitter.com/davidgaider/status/899643777534443521) (lead writer for *Dragon Age: Origins*), I'd assume there was no direct inspiration from the Night's Watch when creating the Grey Wardens

[image: Link to David Gaider's tweet]

> Sure, because those books were the first fantasy tales to ever have an
>   order of knights like that.

Comment: Nice answer. Hope you don't mind me adding an image. Our usual format is provide the image and then quote the text for those that can't see it.

Comment: @Edlothiad I was actually going to but was interrupted

Comment: Ah ok. Well there it is for you :)

Comment: Quickly skimming through both of these, it seems crazy for people to assume it came from ASOIAF (having neither played the game or read those books).  It sounds a lot like the "Children of the Light" from Wheel of Time, which also aren't unique at all.

Comment: @JMac personnaly I think the Grey Wardens are more similar to the Witchers

Comment: @JMac I would say the Children of the Light are more similar to the Templars in Dragon Age - they even have antagonistic relationships with the mages.  The Nights Watch / Grey Wardens are more like Borderlanders where they're defending the southerners from the Blight and people in the south dont even believe in Trollocs and stuff.